# Subdatasheet for Multiple Tables

Tags: ms-access

Good Afternoon All,

Looking to see if there's a solution for the question I'm having with MS Access.  I have a table that is a summary list of items "Box Numbers."  For each of these "Box Numbers" there is an individual table that lists the contents of the box itself. What I'm wondering is if there's a way for this "summary table" to list the contents of each box in a Subdatasheet?

I've added a Subdatasheet but I'm unsure if I need to create a query that pulls in the information from my tables or if the contents of each table need to be listed on one "Master Table"

Please let me know if there is a better way to organize my data or any suggestions that can help in the efficiency of this database.  Thank you for your time.

Mike.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of one table with box contents for all the boxes you have a separate table for each box?

Comment: Yes. I have a "master" table that list all my boxes with their number.  I also have individual tables for each box and those tables list the contents of the boxes.

Comment: Well, apart for the fact that this is horrible design, assuming your tables (or at least the fields you need from those tables) are similar enough  you can create a query to `UNION` these tables into one, which will allow the subtadasheet functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  Managed to get it to work how I was wanting, regardless of my horrible design.